# Can log4j compress a log file after file size pass 2MB

Tags: java, cron, log4j

What I want is this: Just like Glassfish 3 server log, if the log file pass certain file size(like 2MB), the log file will automatically zip itself, so that the log file will not become too large. I am not sure if this is done via `log` api or `cron` api. Is it possible to obtain what I describe above using `log4j` or is there some type of `cron` process involve here? Here is my property file for log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, LOG , stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}:%m%n
# log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG.File=C:\\dev\\harry\\data\\logs\\core.log
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}:%m%n
# log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=INFO
```

Comment: can you please post the way you achieve your requirements, facing similar requirement... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the log4j extras project[log4j extras project](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/) there are many useful appenders that can be used. In particular the with the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) configured with the [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) can automatically compress the rolled file. I don't know if the [SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html) does the same, and the documentation is scarse.

I think that it would be easy to build a custom RollingPolicy that is SizeBased and compress  the output, given that all the ingredients are present in the Log4j extras project (even the compression of the file). It is basically the same code as the TimeBased policy, implementing the `isTriggeringEvent` method to be the same as the SizeBased policy.

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Basically to overcome the size limit of log files, we used to create appenders 
log files if size limit increase beyond max size.
Please check below article[Rolling file appenders](http://article-stack.com/education/log4j-fileappender-advanced.amty)